# Fully qualified table name in postgreSQL select query

Tags: postgresql

Simple question, however google can't help in reasonable time.
Ok, I have **user** table in **my_db** database with **id** column.
I want to run very simple query

```
SELECT id FROM user;
```

but it fails.

> ERROR:  column "id" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT id FROM user;

Can you imagine?

Ok, Running

```
SELECT * FROM user;
```

outputs the list of internal postgresql database users, which is nothing to do with my users, it's data from completely another [internal] database.
However, connection with my_db was established.

Comment: Please, make your comments as answer, so I will pick it up as a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`user` is an internal function (and a reserved word) returning the currently logged in user.

To use that as your own identifier, you need to quote it:

```
select id 
from "user"
```

or

```
select id 
from public."user".
```

But you should really avoid reserved words as table names (or any name that requires quoting the identifier)

Answer (score 4):

The following query can be rewritten as

```
SELECT id FROM my_db.public.user;
```

Where **id** is column, **my_db** is database, **user** is table name, **public** - is the schema. More about schemas:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html
So you don't have to rename the table name.

Comment: You don't need to need to include the current database name, because you can't do cross-db queries anyway.